# Firefox plugin that intercepts certain HTTP requests

Tags: http, firefox, plugins, intercept

Is there a way to make a Firefox plugin intercept certain requests and respond to them without hitting the network?

Example: every time the browser is about to request http://www.example.com/page.html, the plugin automatically returns "Hello world!" for that page.

Cheers!

Comment: Clarification: I need to programatically intercept and respond to certain http requests, without the http request ever going to the network.

Comment: Check out the answer which proposed Fiddler. It matches your needs and it's an advanced tool.

Comment: did you find a solution? i want to do the same...

Answer (score 8):

[Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/966) is a good one.

> Use tamperdata to view and modify
> HTTP/HTTPS headers and post
> parameters.
>
> Security test web
> applications by modifying POST
> parameters.

You can checkout tamper data sources and see how the extension works in [mozdev](http://tamperdata.mozdev.org/source.html) and borrow some ideas, or get in touch with the author in `adamsplugins [AT] gmail {DOT} com`.

I don't know if it's exactly what you're looking for, but it's really powerful. I use it a lot with [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/1843), so you can edit your pages on the fly and test for some behaviors.

Comment: This is a plugin - I need to know how to write a plugin that does something similar. If you know where the tamper source code is, that would be awesome!

Comment: in tamper data u still hit the server, if u want to edit the response use fiddler, an external proxy

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the responses Fiddler is your friend. You can even modify libraries and add scripts on your will.

http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0):

You could craft an extension that "rewrites" the  anchor elements and inserts the javascript you need.

I am pretty sure you can do this with a Greasemonkey script but it's been a while.  I know you can definitely do this on Chrome.

Comment: I actually need to modify the http traffic, and intercept certain requests without the request going to the server